# Using VBA copy and paste data from one sheet to the other including headers and add a blank row between the headers and actual data

Tags: vba, excel

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnVII.png)
Consider this as my sample data. Now I want to write a VBA script which copies a part of this data into a new excel sheet.

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKIE9.png)
This is what I want. As can be seen I want to leave a row blank between header and the data and add something for eg here (Pius), but when I try to do it, my data gets overwritten.
The code which I wrote for my actual data looks like this.

```
Sheets("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Here the headers are from row A8 to O8, and then I want to leave a blank row. But I don’t know how to add this as all my data gets copy pasted together. So is there a way I can 1st paste the headers then add a blank row in between and then my data gets pasted below?
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The example below is based on the sample data you provided -- which has your headers on row 1. So you'll have to change the code to match what you'd like to do. But this will illustrate how to do it.

Notice that you do not have to `Select` the sheets or ranges to make this work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Dim fromRange As Range
    Dim toRange As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)")
    Set dstWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DestinationWorksheetName")

    '--- copy header row
    lastCol = srcWS.Cells(1, srcWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set fromRange = srcWS.Range("A1").Resize(1, lastCol)
    Set toRange = dstWS.Range("A1").Resize(1, lastCol)
    toRange.Value = fromRange.Value

    '--- copy data area
    lastRow = srcWS.Cells(srcWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set fromRange = srcWS.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow, lastCol)
    Set toRange = dstWS.Range("A3").Resize(lastRow, lastCol)
    toRange.Value = fromRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Peter, but I am looking to automate the process and not just manually copying and pasting the headers and the data. So is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fully automated." The example I gave automatically determines how many columns you have and adjusts itself. It also determines how many rows of data there are. So the "copy paste" you were asking in your original post is answered with an automated example.  Perhaps there is another part of your question I'm missing, or is a separate question? The example is not a manual copy-paste.